# why viewPager addOnPageChangeListener works with tab clicking and break on scrolling pages?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `viewPager` of four different tabs, i'm using `addOnPageChangeListener` to manage page scrolling, the following code is trying to get a `view` from the first `fragment` when clicking on a `button` on the `fourth` fragment, this works fine when i click on tabs and break when i scroll the pages, which i couldn't find a reason why, the exception i get is a `java.lang.NullPointerException` for the `EditTest` view [error](http://pastie.org/10788224)

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float 
                         positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if(position == 3){
                EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
                Log.d("Hello", title.getText().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

link to gif showing the problem [here](http://content.screencast.com/users/minagabriel/folders/Default/media/cbbda0ee-e805-4d28-a1e9-327283c6bc30/2016-04-06_21-45-21.gif)

i have tried to move this code to `onPageSelected` and it didn't work, i also tried to get the `fragment view` using the following code and no luck:

```
public View getFragmentView(int position) {
    String fragmentD = "android:switcher:" + viewPager.getId() + ":" + position;
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment =
             getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentD);
    return fragment.getView();
}
```

**question** is why this works with tab clicking and doesn't with scrolling?

Comment: can you add your logcat

Comment: its linked above in the question under error @TanTran

Comment: add the code when you setup viewPager, I'm not sure but maybe you need this code: viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

Comment: That worked @TanTran so i should retain the idle state of the page when scrolling to keep it in the view hierarchy... Thanks.. try to answer this question

Comment: try returning getCount() as 4?

Comment: @Tan's answer is correct. setOffscreenPageLimit is set to 1 as default. and it means only 1 pages either side of the current page retained and the rest recreated when needed as official doc says. to tell why works when tab clicked we need to know how you set up tab layout

Answer (score 0):

You must call it in OnCreate

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText title;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
}
}
```

And at  public void onPageSelected(int position)

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float 
                     positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

     if(position == 3){
            Log.d("Hello", title.getText().toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but why do you think this may work?